# Socket object return null in an Activity Binding to a Service

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, android-service

I have an issue regarding a socket object that I pass through a Service instance into my Android activity.

The socket object always returns null and I do not understand why. 
I use the same approach in other activities and it works fine. Could anyone have a look at it?

Here is my code:

```
**Service class code:**

public class SocketService extends Service {
    // Create subclass of IBinder and bind it to local class instance
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();      
public class LocalBinder extends Binder { 
    SocketService getService() { 
        return SocketService.this; 
        }
    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
        try {
            socket = new SocketIO(URL);
            socket.connect(new IOCallback() {

                // Tell if connection was established
                @Override
                public void onConnect(){    
                }

                // Server Message
                @Override
                public void on(String event, final IOAcknowledge ack,
                        Object... arg) {
            }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnect() {
                    socket.reconnect();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(SocketIOException arg0) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "No Connection to host");
                    error = true;
            }    

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {        
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(JSONObject arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {    
                }   
            });

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("error", "Wrong Server URL" + e); }
        } else {
            Log.e("ERROR", "No connection possible");
            }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    socket.disconnect();
    stopSelf();
}

public SocketIO getSocket(){
    return socket;
}
```

And here the activity with the null socket object:

```
Activity code:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

 socketConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            socketService = binder.getService();
            isBound = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            socketService = null;
        }
       };

        // Bind to socket service
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(ContactMenuActivity.this, SocketService.class);
        bindService(serviceIntent, socketConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


        socket = socketService.getSocket(); // This code always returns null 
but only for this activity, it works with other activities with same approach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my question. Apparently binding to a service can take a bit of time, longer than the startup of my activity in either case.

The solution was to check for the return value of the IBinder object as soon as the intent has connected to the service:

```
Service Class

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Connected to service");
    return mBinder;
}

Activity Class

if (mBinder != null)
socket = socketService.getSocket();
```